# not able to get managedObjectContext object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, sprite-kit

I am new to CoreData. I am using sprite kit to create a game. I set up core data into my project in appdelegate.h and appdelegate.m. I can fetch data in appdelegate by using following code

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Current" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

 [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
 NSError *error;
 NSLog(@"%@",[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]);
```

I want to fetch data in another class (view). I was not able to get managedObjectContext object, since I could not call self.managedObjectContext.
What should I do in order to fetch coredata from another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have some class with NSManagedObjectContext, e.g. 'DBManger'

```
@interface DBManager : NSObject

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

@end
```

In your ViewController use:

```
DBManager *dbManager = [[DBManager alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = dbManager.managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Current" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
NSLog(@"%@",[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]);
```

If your ManagedContext is in AppDelegate, get it:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;
```